# What is the problem in this shell code (Django and sql)

Tags: django, sqlite

[image]

I got this error in my shell code.

Comment: You have to make migrations and apply they, this error means that origin column doesn't exists on fligth table

Comment: column origin is absent in flights_flight

Answer (score 0):

You've to use this, it is because till now you've only declared the table not exactly created in you database, this will create/update table details in the database

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Then reload the shell and run this command

Comment: I added the origin column in models.py and I made the migrations and apllied it but it said no migrations to apply

Comment: Can you share your migration file? does origin added inside it ?